# Canvas On Draw Method

Tags: android, canvas

I am new to android programming and I am trying to create a green circle image out of the screen. I tried using canvas to draw but it always show an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Paint.setColor(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.jordanong09.handeyegame.GameActivity.onDraw(GameActivity.java:61)
            at com.example.jordanong09.handeyegame.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:47)
```

Below are my codes for my programme:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textViewTime, textViewScore;
    int timeLeft,score;
    float xcoord,ycoord,radius = 100;
    Paint paint;
    Canvas canvas1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


        String timeData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("timeDuration");
        if(timeData == "30sec"){
            timeLeft = 30;
        }

        textViewTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        textViewScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewScore);
        textViewTime.setText(timeData);
        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass (30000, 1000);
        timer.start();
        onDraw(canvas1);

    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)
    {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point screenSize = new Point();
        display.getSize(screenSize);
        int width = screenSize.x;
        int height = screenSize.y;
        Random random = new Random();
        xcoord = random.nextFloat() * width;
        ycoord = random.nextFloat() * height;
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(xcoord, ycoord, radius, paint);
    }
```

I really dunno what is wrong with it because I have been researching online for solutions. Hope I could hear some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Paint object is not initialised correctly. You should call

```
paint = new Paint();
```

before calling

```
paint.setColor();
```

Otherwise paint is null, and you can't call methods on null.

Comment: i initialised the paint alr. but i get this error instead: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawCircle(float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)' on a null object reference

Comment: You need to instantiate the Canvas object too.

Comment: Like Sanjeet said, canvas needs to be initialised as a new Canvas() object as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should go by creating a custom view and adding it as a child to one of your view group. Here is an example code. Hope this will help.

```
/**
 * Created by sanjeet on 2/2/16.
 */
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textViewTime, textViewScore;
    int timeLeft, score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        textViewTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        textViewScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewScore);
        /*Create a ViewGroup in your layout to contain this custom GameView instance */
        LinearLayout gameViewContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.custom_view_container);
        gameViewContainer.addView(new GameView(this));

    }



    class GameView extends View {

       Paint paint;
       int width;
       int height;
       private float radius=100;
       Random random;
       public GameView(Context context) {
           super(context);
           paint = new Paint();
           paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
           paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
           Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
           Point screenSize = new Point();
           display.getSize(screenSize);
           width = screenSize.x;
           height = screenSize.y;
           random = new Random();
       }


       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           super.onDraw(canvas);
           float xcoord = random.nextFloat() * width;
           float ycoord = random.nextFloat() * height;
           canvas.drawCircle(xcoord, ycoord, radius, paint);

       }

   }


}
```

Comment: what do u mean by adding a custom view?

Comment: I dont understand the part by creating a viewgroup in my layout that contain this custom gameview instance